# Conditional format dynamic calendar based upon check-in and check-out of guests

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have made a dynamic calendar [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjaRiSa6uN_19l9pMwmoiczk0gbp?e=kwMCNS) which you can view/download to test with.

You will see each day of the month has 3 cells. The centre cell is to identify critical change overs which occurs when one guest leaves on the same day another arrives. In this scenario, the left cell will be filled light red, centre deep red and right cell light red. When a guest checks-out but there is not a critical change over, the left cell will be filled light red and centre and right cells both green (such as Dec 21st 2019 as shown below). The image below indicates the intended pattern in other scenarios.

I now need to create a formula for conditional formatting the 3 cells within each `[date]`. If my data (on seperate tab) did not have blank rows when the property is unoccupied, I could use the formula `=COUNTIFS([Check-in_range],"<="&[date],[Check-out_range],">="&[date])>0` to detect when the arrival/departure days were. However, with blank rows for each week of the rental season within the data (for personal reasons), how can I refine the formula?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the change of circumstances, I will craft a new answer here.

Suppose you have the following **named ranges**:

- **Start_Date** being all the start dates in your look up table;
- **End_Date** being all the end dates (which is `Start_Date + Nights`) in your look up table;
- **Name** being all the names in your look up table;
- **CCO** being all the critical-change-over dates which can be found using the following formula if you have named the columns as shown below in a **Table**: `=IFERROR(IF(AND(MATCH([@[End Date]],[Start Date],0)>0,AA6<>0,AA7<>0),[@[End Date]],""),"")` where `AA6` is the name in the same row while `AA7` is the name in the next row.

[image: Named Ranges]

Then follow the steps to set up the conditional formatting. **Please note the following are performed in Excel but not google-sheets**, and all cell references are based on the previous [sample workbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rv0Esqcuyi7PYQ6HxNduBNxd_Huli8n-/view?usp=sharing) you provided in your previous question. The link I provided is the final workbook with all the conditional formats so you can download it and test it out in Excel.

To set up the formatting for the **critical-change-over** date:

```
| Formatting for CCO |                     |                                    |
|--------------------|---------------------|------------------------------------|
| Section            | Formatting Rule     | Formatting Range                   |
| Sun                | =MATCH($D5,CCO,0)>0 | $C$5,$C$12,$C$19,$C$26,$C$33,$C$40 |
| Mon                | =MATCH($G5,CCO,0)>0 | $F$5,$F$12,$F$19,$F$26,$F$33,$F$40 |
| Tue                | =MATCH($J5,CCO,0)>0 | $I$5,$I$12,$I$19,$I$26,$I$33,$I$40 |
| Wed                | =MATCH($M5,CCO,0)>0 | $L$5,$L$12,$L$19,$L$26,$L$33,$L$40 |
| Thu                | =MATCH($P5,CCO,0)>0 | $O$5,$O$12,$O$19,$O$26,$O$33,$O$40 |
| Fri                | =MATCH($S5,CCO,0)>0 | $R$5,$R$12,$R$19,$R$26,$R$33,$R$40 |
| Sat                | =MATCH($V5,CCO,0)>0 | $U$5,$U$12,$U$19,$U$26,$U$33,$U$40 |
```

To set up the formatting for each **day section**:

```
| Section | Formatting Rule                        | Formatting Range                                                      |
|---------|----------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Sun     | =ISTEXT(LOOKUP($D5-1,Start_Date,Name)) | $B$5,$B$12,$B$19,$B$26,$B$33,$B$40                                    |
| Sun-Mon | =ISTEXT(LOOKUP($D5,Start_Date,Name))   | $C$5:$E$5,$C$12:$E$12,$C$19:$E$19,$C$26:$E$26,$C$33:$E$33,$C$40:$E$40 |
| Mon-Tue | =ISTEXT(LOOKUP($G5,Start_Date,Name))   | $F$5:$H$5,$F$12:$H$12,$F$19:$H$19,$F$26:$H$26,$F$33:$H$33,$F$40:$H$40 |
| Tue-Wed | =ISTEXT(LOOKUP($J5,Start_Date,Name))   | $I$5:$K$5,$I$12:$K$12,$I$19:$K$19,$I$26:$K$26,$I$33:$K$33,$I$40:$K$40 |
| Wed-Thu | =ISTEXT(LOOKUP($M5,Start_Date,Name))   | $L$5:$N$5,$L$12:$N$12,$L$19:$N$19,$L$26:$N$26,$L$33:$N$33,$L$40:$N$40 |
| Thu-Fri | =ISTEXT(LOOKUP($P5,Start_Date,Name))   | $O$5:$Q$5,$O$12:$Q$12,$O$19:$Q$19,$O$26:$Q$26,$O$33:$Q$33,$O$40:$Q$40 |
| Fri-Sat | =ISTEXT(LOOKUP($S5,Start_Date,Name))   | $R$5:$T$5,$R$12:$T$12,$R$19:$T$19,$R$26:$T$26,$R$33:$T$33,$R$40:$T$40 |
| Sat-Sun | =ISTEXT(LOOKUP($V5,Start_Date,Name))   | $U$5:$V$5,$U$12:$V$12,$U$19:$V$19,$U$26:$V$26,$U$33:$V$33,$U$40:$V$40 |
```

Please note, the formatting for **CCO** must sit above the formatting for **day section** in the `Conditional Formatting Rules Manager` as demonstrated below:

[image: CFRM]

> A tip here is to use `Format Painter` to quickly "create" conditional formatting rules across sections, however each copied rule needs to be modified with the correct **formatting range** and **formatting rule** as given above.
>
> A second tip, you can copy and paste one set of **formatting range** and **formatting rule** as text string to a cell, make a few copies of the text strings, then use the `Find and Replace` function (as demonstrated below) to bulk change the cell references and then update the **formatting range** and **formatting rule** one by one.

[image: FNR]

Please note there will be no blank or white cells in the row of days header. All day headers are filled with light green colour as the default background colour, and the colour will be changed by the formatting rules.

Also I have set up the following rule to "hide" zeros returned by your VLOOKUP function in the `NAME`, `EMAIL` and `PHONE` row. The logic is to format the font colour to white for `0 (zero)` if the default background colour of the row is white, or light grey for row defaulted to light grey background. You can set up the rule for one row, and then use `Format Painter` to copy the same rule for similar rows.

[image: hide zeros]

Here is a live demo:

[image: Live Demo]

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Terry W, you are a true legend for this. Massively appreciated! Thanks

Comment: @JamesB you are welcome :) a suggestion here, if you change the starting date of month to starting date of week, your calendar may have a week on week rolling effect which might be more user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

If the Conditional Formatting formula from your question worked fine for you the adjustment to work with blank rows is relatively simple. Try this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS([Check-in_range],"<="&[date],[Check-out_range],">="&[date],[Name_range],"<>")>0
```

In this case [Name_range] should refer to column `D` of you sheet `Data`.

However, as far as I can see that formula will only apply to the cells that contain the date, which will not lead to the picture you povided. The line breaks make this a bit trickier to do. Let me know if you need help with that as well.

For a bit of simplification I would recommend coloring the cells with a light green since that is the default. The Conditional Formatting will then overwrite the cell color if necessary.